# Code gets stuck while writing to a Network Stream

Tags: c#, network-programming, windows-services

I am reading a .bin file and writing it into a Stream. Later, I am reading that stream object and then writing it into a Network Stream. Code is as following:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFirmware(Stream _stream)
        {                
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                _tcpclient = new TcpClient();
                _tcpclient.Connect(_deviceip, port);

                _stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                m_NetworkStream = _tcpclient.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                m_ReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int readcount = 0;
                m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_ReadBuffer, 0, m_ReadBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(EndReceive), null);
                await Task.Run(() =>
                 {
                     while ((readcount = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                     {
                         m_NetworkStream.Write(buffer, 0, readcount);
                         m_NetworkStream.Flush();

                     }
                 });
                success = true;                              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
            return success;
      }
```

Normally, this code works fine, but sometimes on an IP Address, the code gets stuck at `m_NetworkStream.Write(buffer, 0, readcount);`. The thing is, I am updating the status in UI based on `success` value, but the code gets hanged at above mentioned line and doesn't come out at all. No exception is thrown at all to identify the issue. So, in UI the status is not updated, and unexpected result is produced. I am not able to identify the issue. Help of any kind will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Also, I have to do an operation in parallel. The code for EndReceive is as follows:

```
private void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                int nBytes;
                nBytes = m_NetworkStream.EndRead(ar);
                if (nBytes > 0)
                {
                    string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_ReadBuffer, 0, nBytes);
                    DeviceStatus status = new DeviceStatus();

                    string[] readlines = res.Split(new string[] { CRLF }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (string readline in readlines)
                    {
                        if (readline.StartsWith("CODE"))
                        {
                            status.code = Convert.ToInt32(readline.Replace("CODE=", ""));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    status.deviceip = this._deviceip;
                    status.port = this.port;
                    status.DeviceID = this._DeviceID;
                    status.FirmwareID = this._FirmwareID;
                    status.FilePath = this._Path;
                    StatusUpdate(status);

                    m_ReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                }


            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ods)
            {
                return;
            }
           if (_tcpclient.Connected)
                m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_ReadBuffer, 0, m_ReadBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(EndReceive), null);
        }
```

Comment: Did you check if the client side receives the file..?

Comment: No, the client side doesn't get any update. It's literally stuck.

Comment: Do you need to write the .bin file's bytes into a stream first?  What is the reason for this?

Comment: @JamesHarcourt: Bin files contain the firmware details for the devices. (Devices firmware information are contained only in bin files). I need to upgrade firmware of a device using this.

Comment: Maybe the client's computer's port is using and is block? So you can't connect to the client side??

Comment: Your OP says "reading a .bin file and writing it into a Stream" ... it is the "writing it to a stream" bit which I need to understand.  If you just want the bytes and to write them to the network stream, you don't need to involve another stream and the while loop etc ...

Comment: @User2012384: I think the port is not blocked because _tcpclient.Connect(_deviceip, port); doesn't throw any exception. Moreover, the code gets stuck after writing few bytes of data to network stream.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt: From the client, i get .bin files which needs to be pushed to devices. So, i am converting .bin files into a file stream. Then, based on TCPClient, i am writing data byte by byte from stream to network stream.

Comment: @Saket ok I think you can just read the .bin file into a byte aray and then write that to the network stream without putting into another stream first.  See my answer below which shows the code.

Comment: Is it Windows Forms application?

Comment: @AntonKedrov: No, it's running under windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should have a while loop in order to write bytes read from a file (from disk) to a network stream ... you can just read all the bytes and write to the stream and flush in one move.

You can also add a write timeout to specify how much time can pass before the stream write operation fails, to prevent any possibility of 'hanging'.

With these modifications, the code would look something like this:

```
 // make the tcp connection to the remote endpoint
 _tcpclient = new TcpClient();
 _tcpclient.Connect(_deviceip, port);

 // read the file bytes in one operation
 var allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileNameOnDisk);

 // get the network stream
 m_NetworkStream = _tcpclient.GetStream();

 // wait a max of 500ms for the write operation to happen
 m_NetworkStream.WriteTimeout = 500;

 // write the file bytes to the stream and flush without while/stream/seek etc.
 m_NetworkStream.Write(allBytes, 0, allBytes.Length);
 m_NetworkStream.Flush();
```

And when you've finished with the stream:

```
 m_NetworkStream.Close();
 m_NetworkStream.Dispose();
```

Comment: The file size that i am trying to write is of approx. 100 Mb. Isn't it advisable to write data in chunks if data size is large? Won't it throw exception at later stage when I try to write such large data at once over TCP Client?

Comment: Actually it isn't so much a problem writing the large number of bytes to the stream - the TCP layer will break this into appropriate packet sizes for transmission.  What might be a problem is increasing the memory consumption of your app by 100MB during this operation. However, you would be doing this anyway with your previous approach.

Comment: I will try your suggestions and let you know. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Good luck.  As long as you release your reference to the byte array once the transmission is complete, the garbage collector will free up that 100MB of application memory pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It seem odd that you starting to read from network stream (`m_NetworkStream.BeginRead(...)`) and right away in another thread starting to write into same stream (`m_NetworkStream.Write(...)`). I would suggest to finish reading first and then start writing. Also you could use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy data between streams.

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFirmware(Stream fileStream, IPEndPoint deviceEP)
{
    bool success = false;

    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(deviceEP);
        NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

        BeginReadFromDevice(networkStream);

        // send bin data to device
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(networkStream);

        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return success;
}

private void BeginReadFromDevice(Stream networkStream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(EndReceive), null);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have to do an operation in parallel to writing the data. Please check the code for EndReceive in question.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. Thanks for your help.